# Including code to be compiled only if static constexpr is met C++

Tags: c++, constexpr

Is it possible to include code to be compiled only if a static constexpr has a certain value?

Take this for instance

`static constexpr auto VERSION_MIN = 123;`

If the number were set to 124 include the code to be compiled otherwise exclude it.

Basically I have two source packages which are identical except for a few lines of code which are considered extra or a minor difference.

I just want to make a universal application where I don't need to recompile to switch versions.

How would I check to see if a constexpr is equal to 124, would I just use a basic control structure? Or is there another way to do this?

Comment: I don't have time to expand into a full answer, but "constexpr if" was created for this use case.  It exists in c++17, there exist backports of it as well.

Comment: This sort of thing is traditionally done with macros.

Comment: And you do need to recompile if you change a `static constexpr` constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with gcc 4.9:

```
static constexpr auto VERSION_MIN = 123;

void myFunction()
{
    if (VERSION_MIN == 123) {
        printf("This is version 123\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("This is another version\n");
    }
}
```

On Linux (don't now such tools for Win) you can check that the binary does not contain the string "This is another version\n".

Thus you can replace

```
#ifdef VERSION_MIN 123
    printf("This is version 123\n");
#else
    printf("This is another version\n");
#endif
```

My IDE (QtCreator) handle the "pure" C++ code better than the preprocessor code.

Comment: I use linux too :) I'll try this out and see how it goes, the version is actually compared from a file in lua so this is why I think I would not need to recompile.

Comment: I haven't tried it yet, but it does look like this could work. I use the terminal to compile and sublime text to edit and meld to run comparison :)

Comment: You can review with `cd build-folder && grep -rnw . -e "This is another version\n"` whether or not the text is in code

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 (If you are using it) has solved this problem with Build Configurations. You can create a new Build Configuration and then give it a preprocessor directive to insert automatically into the code when it builds. This will allow you to create a different Build Configuration for each 'Version' of your code and then you can 'batch build' to build each version; without changing the actual source code for each version.

To do this go to Configuration Manager (Under Release/Debug Dropdown) then  then give your Version a name and copy settings from your previous building configuration. After you have created a Build Configuration select it in the Configuration drop down to make it active and then go to Project Properties (Alt+p+p) -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions and add a preprocessor to control what code is compiled in that version and what isn't.

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
std::cout << "data data data" << std::endl;
#endif //_DEBUG
```